# How come there are two accusative objects here "das geht dich einen Dreck an"? (so it seems)

Tags: accusative

I failed with the object analysis of the following sentence:

> Das <sup><sup>Subjekt</sup></sup>   geht <sup><sup>Verb</sup></sup>  dich <sup><sup>Akk-Objekt(!?)</sup></sup>  einen Dreck <sup><sup>Akk-Objekt(!?)</sup></sup>  an.

I know there are instances, in which one finds, on top of the accusative object, some other noun in accusative, like in:

> Diesen Monat werde ich den Arzt drei Mal besuchen.

There, one has *Arzt* and *Monat* in accusative, but one is a time complement. In the first sentence one has an instance of other nature, I guess.

If there are indeed two direct objects, why? If not, which is the right analysis?

Comment: Ist "diesen Monat" Kurzform von "im Lauf diesen Monats"?

Comment: "diesen Monat" ist völlig richtig. Und es ist keine Kurzform, denn sonnst wäre auch "diese Woche" eine Kurzform von "im Laufe dieser Woche" und dass man in einer Kurzform den Kasus ändert halte ich für sehr unwahrscheinlich.

Comment: Note that *diesen Monat* is not an accusative object in your second example sentence, but an adverbial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es handelt sich hierbei um das [Objektsprädikativ](http://www.cafe-lingua.de/deutsche-grammatik/objektspraedikativ.php), dessen Funktion es ist, das Akkusativobjekt genauer zu bestimmen. Es ist somit ein Prädikativum, genau wie das Prädikatsnomen, welches bekanntlich das Subjekt genauer bestimmt.

Es ist folglich das Komplement zu einem sonst unvollständigen Satz. Vergleiche:

- Vollständiger Satz, braucht keint Komplement

  > Ich lese.
  >   Er schimpft.
- Unvollständiger Satz, braucht ein Komplement

  > *Ich bin.
  >   *Er schimpft ihn.
- Mit Subjektsprädikativ (Prädikatsnomen) bzw. Objektsprädikativ

  > Ich bin Em1.
  >   Er schimpft ihn einen Esel.

Comment: Diese Antwort ist nicht korrekt. Den Beweis liefert eine Umformprobe: Die beiden Akkusativ-Satzglieder aus dem Satz herauslösen, in den Nominativ setzen und mit «sein» verbinden. Ein Prädikativum ist es nur dann, wenn die Umformung eine Aussage macht, die im ursprünglichen Satz enthalten ist. Beispiel: _Ich nenne dich einen Lügner → Du bist ein Lügner._ Diese Aussage ist im ursprünglichen Satz enthalten, also liegt ein Prädikativum vor. Beim Satz hier macht die Umformung _Du bist ein Dreck_ keine Aussage, die im ursprünglichen Satz enthalten ist, also liegt kein Prädikativum vor.

Answer (score 11):

There are very few verbs that can take two accusative objects.

- jemanden etwas angehen (limitations with regards to what can be used instead of "etwas")
- jemanden etwas lehren
- jemanden etwas nennen/heißen
- jemanden etwas fragen

There might be a couple more, but that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in your analysis. The [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=angehen) also gives two accusative objekts for the verb *angehen.*

But you should be aware, that for second object there is only a small number of possibilities like

- *einen Dreck*
- *viel*
- *nichts* (also expanded)
- *eine Menge*
- *ein Bisschen*
- *etwas*

Comment: Und natürlich beliebige Umschreibungen der Genannten.

Comment: Etwa "einen feuchten Kehricht".

Answer (score 3):

Verben mit doppeltem Akkusativ

Wie schon gesagt wurde, solche Verbkonstruktionen sind selten.

Bei den Verben "angehen" und "kosten" ist der zweite Akkusativ eigentlich
kein Akkusativobjekt, sondern eine wieviel-Angabe:

- Das geht dich nichts/einenDreck/einen feuchten Staub an.
- Das kostet dich einen Hunderter.