# Ist „existieren“ ein doppelnominativfähiges Verb?

Tags: verb, nominative

[Hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11074/how-come-there-are-two-accusative-objects-here-das-geht-dich-einen-dreck-an) wurde der Doppelakkusativ infrage gestellt. Den Antworten gemäß sollte man vielleicht einfach auch nachvollziehen können, dass es einen Doppelnominativ gäbe. In der Tat sind *sein*, *heißen* u.ä. Verben, die allem Anschein nach zwei Nomen in Nominativ erlauben.

Kann man Sätze mit *es* im Vorfeld und dem Verb *existieren* mit Doppelnominativ?

> Es existiert einen Grund ... (klingt falsch)

oder

> Es existiert ein Grund... (klingt richtig)

Sollte man erklärungslos akzeptieren, dass es halt so sei?

*Edit. Anscheinend ging ich völlig irrtümlicherweise davon aus, dass* es *ein Subjekt in vorigem Satz ist. Vgl.*

> *Es gibt ein**en** Grund* (richtig)

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage nicht. Das "es" ist ein reines Füllwort hier, das einzige Subjekt ist "Morphismus". Vergleiche "Es ist mein Vater ein Idiot."... nicht schön aber vom Prinzip her das gleiche.

Comment: Na gut, ich verstehe.  Was ich nicht verstehe ist warum "Es gibt einen Grund dafür" mit *Akk* und "Es existiert ein Grund" mit *Nom.* gingen. *Es* ist da auch ein Füllwort, das aber den Platz eines Nominativobjektes nimmt. Oder vertue ich mich vielleicht.

Comment: Das "es" dort heißt "false subject", siehe z. B. http://www.dartmouth.edu/~german/Grammatik/WordOrder/WordOrder.html (suche nach "false subject").

Comment: @karoshi.. the term "false subject" is misleading. It could just as well be called "false object". It has nothing to do with the subject and using the word "subject" fools people into thinking it has.

Comment: Well, then complain with the author of the page I linked, I took the term from there :-) I'm sure there's a more exact technical term; it's not a german-specific phenomenon.

Comment: @karoshi... well you're the one who linked to the page with the misleading term ;). Dartmouth is a good source but is has no naming authority so why the link to begin with?

Comment: Duden: "kündigt ein ins Mittel- oder Nachfeld des Satzes gerücktes (hervorzuhebendes) Subjekt an oder einen im Mittel- oder Nachfeld stehenden [verkürzten] Subjekt- oder Objektsatz". The link was the one I had immediately available without searching, and I was sure that it covered that case.

Comment: @karoshi... the Duden has the same problem and doesn't seem to understand what a filler is. In the sentence "Es wurde gefeiert und gesungen.", the "es" doesn't hint at or foreshadow anything because there is no subject. And yet, it's the very same "es" as in OP's example. The one that replaces a subject or object-clause is different in so far as that it might stay in the sentence even after rearranging it. "Mir misfällt (es), wie du die Haare hast.". Duden needs to do its homework there and stop copying older texts.

Comment: @Emanuel, Yeah? The Duden? In any case, after some search I see that most sources use the term "Vorfeld", eg "Expletives/Platzhalter-es zur Markierung des Vorfelds", or "Hingegen gibt es im Deutschen ein spezielles Expletiv, um das Vorfeld in einem Verbzweitsatz zu besetzen", etc. That looks to me more accurate and avoids any reference to grammatical roles.

Answer (score 8):

Die Antwort ist: nein.

"Existieren" hat kein richtiges Komplement. Das "es" im Beispiel ist das berühmt-berüchtigte Füll-Es, das hier immer wieder zu Fragen führt. Dieses "es" ist funktional nicht das gleiche, wie das Regen-Es.

> Es regnet heute.
>   Es gibt einen Grund.

In diesen beiden Sätzen ist "es" das Subjekt, und es bleibt erhalten, wenn man den Satz umstellt.

> Heute regnet es.
>   Einen Grund gibt es.

Das "es" im Beispiel mit "existieren" ist KEIN Subjekt. Es hat keinen Einfluss auf die Konjugation des Verbs und es verschwindet, sobald man den Satz umsortiert.

> Es existiert ein Grund dafür.
>   Es existieren viele Gründe dafür.
>   Viele Gründe existieren dafür.

Die einzige Aufgabe dieses Füll-Es ist, die Position 1 zu besetzen, da der Satz sonst wie ein Frage aussieht.

Answer (score 7):

In deiner Frage und deinem Kommentar zur Frage tauchen drei verschiedene Phänomene auf:

- Bei einem **Doppel-/Gleichsetzungsnominativ** erfordert das Verb zwei Nominative; der eine ist ein Subjekt, der zweite ein Nominativobjekt. Solche Verben sind beispielsweise *sein* oder *werden*:

  > Er (=Nom.) ist ein kluger Junge (=Nom.).
  >   Sie (=Nom.) wird Polizistin (=Nom.).
- Das Pronomen *es* wird als **Subjekt** des Satzes verwendet:

  > Es (=Nom.) gibt einen Grund (=Akk.).
- Das Pronomen *es* wird als **Füllwort** verwendet, um die leere Position vor dem Verb zu füllen:

  > Es (=Nom.) tanzt ein Bi-Ba-Butzemann (=Nom.) ...
  >   Es (=Nom.) existiert ein Grund (=Nom.).

  Rückt das Subjekt des Satzes hinter das Verb, wird die Position vor dem Verb mit dem Füllwort *es* gefüllt. Der Hauptgrund hierfür ist, dass im Deutschen normale Aussagesätze V2-Sätze sind, d. h., das Verb steht an zweiter Position. Und wenn das Subjekt hinter das Verb rückt, muss eben ein Füllwort her. Das ist sehr häufig in der Mathematik anzutreffen, wo Sätze wie

  > Es existiert/existiere ein Homomorphismus.

  idiomatisch sind.

---

Vergleicht man die beiden Sätze

> Es (=Nom.) gibt einen Grund (=Akk.).
>   Es (=Nom.) existiert ein Grund (=Nom.).

so erfüllt das Wort *es* also unterschiedliche Funktionen: Im ersten Satz ist es das Subjekt, das einen Grund "gibt". Im zweiten Satz ist es ein Füllwort, das notwendig wird, weil das Subjekt des Satzes (ein Grund) hinter das Verb rückt:

> Ein Grund existiert.
>   ___ existiert ein Grund.

Die Lücke muss gefüllt werden; wenn hierzu kein Adverb *(Heute existiert ein Grund.)* verwendet wird, benutzt man das Füllsel *es*. Dies ist aber kein Doppel-/Gleichsetzungsnominativ.

Comment: +1 für den Bi-Ba-Butzemann.