# How can be there two accusative in one sentence?

Tags: accusative

I was doing an exercise in German Grammar drill. I found a sentence like that has two accusatives. Are they really accusatives?

> Meine Tante stellte den Blumenstrauß auf den Tisch

"auf" is also dative preposition as I know.

Comment: Could you extend your question to explain why you think there *cannot* be two accusatives in one sentence? That might help us provide an answer that actually addresses your concrete difficulty in understanding the grammar.

Comment: As I know there are always one accusative and one dative. Only for some case there will be two accusatives. Like lehre. Will you please help me regarding this question? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such rule there can only be one accusative per clause.

> Meine Tante stellte den Blumenstrauß auf den Tisch.

*My aunt put the bouquet onto the table.*

What's true is there can only be one **accusative object** per clause. And you only have one: *den Blumenstrauß*. It's the thing put.

*Auf den Tisch* in contrary is a **prepositional object**, because it has a preposition leading it. And **auf** is one of the nine **dual-way prepositions** (*an, auf, hinter, neben, in, über, unter, vor, zwischen)* which may take either accusative or dative, depending on whether a direction or a place is meant. It depends on the verb whether you need a direction, a place or have free choice.

*Stellen* in the meaning "to put" requires a direction. When it takes a place or has no prepositional object at all, it means "to corner".

Comment: There are even verbs that take two accusatives where none of them is a prepositional object, see [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11074/how-come-there-are-two-accusative-objects-here-das-geht-dich-einen-dreck-an?rq=1).

Comment: In that question it's an subject predicative (S is SP to O), not an object of its own.

Comment: Your assertion *[w]hat's true is there can only be one accusative object per clause* is not entirely true. A few verbs like *lehren* can have two accusative objects (and none of them is a predicativum), e.g. *sie lehrt den Schüler den Gebrauch des Akkusativobjekts.*

Comment: A clause with two accusative objects: *Es hat mich einen Euro gekostet*

Comment: *Es hat mich ein Euro gekostet* also uninflected *zwanzig*, prepositional *Es hat mich einiges **an** Kraft gekostet*, dialectally correct *Es hat mich'**en** Kopf gekostet*; *den* may be plausible as voiced variant of LowG. *t*, HighG. *z*, in the sense of French *de* "of" (cp. in Names *ten Brink, Zimbrink, du Mont, von und zu Guttenberg*).