# Ist es möglich, dass ein Satz mehr als eine Dativwortgruppe hat?

Tags: grammatical-case, dative

In dem folgenden Satz:

> InterCitys fahren nur vom Hauptbahnhof in der Innenstadt ab.

Ich glaube "vom Hauptbahnhof" und "in der Innenstadt" sind Dativ (Dativwortgruppen). Lieg ich richtig? aus irgendeinem Grund habe ich gedacht, dass ein Fall in einem Satz nur einmal erscheinen darf.

Comment: Und einmal mehr wurde nicht auf die **Präposition** geachtet.

Comment: *Ich antwortete ihm aus diesem Grund an einem Donnerstag in seinem Büro mit den Händen auf dem Kopf.* Six datives!

Comment: @DavidVogt Nice example :) Would you like to make a full answer out of this?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Ich finde, die Frage müsste überarbeitet werden. *Sind das zwei Dative?* ist zu wenig.

Comment: Ähnliche Frage: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39020/how-can-be-there-two-accusative-in-one-sentence Auch hier scheint der Fragesteller von der irrigen Voraussetzung auszugehen, das ein Fall in einem Satz nur einmal erscheinen darf.

Comment: @userunknown: Danke für die Überarbeitung.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Vorbildliches Beispiel!

Comment: "dass jeder Satz nur ein von vier Fällen haben muss" - sorry, ich kann da allenfalls versuchen zu erraten, was gemeint sein könnte.

Comment: @RHa, dass ein Fall in einem Satz nur einmal erscheinen darf, wie gesagt.

Answer (score 5):

Ja, ganz eindeutig.

Deutsch gehört nicht zu den Sprachen, in denen ein ganzer Satz einen einheitlichen Kasus aufweist. Stattdessen erstreckt ich der Skopus eines Kasus immer nur auf eine Nominalgruppe und wird jeweils von einem anderen Wort *regiert*.

Oft regiert z.B. ein finites Verb einen Nominativ (Subjekt) und einen Akkusativ (Objekt). Eine Präposition regiert einen bestimmten Kasus in ihrem Argument, z.B. Akkusativ oder Dativ, etc.

Da ein Satz aus vielen Einzelteilen bestehen kann, kann es auch viele verschiedene oder gleiche Kasusgruppen geben. Mehrere Dativgruppen sind also nicht ungewöhnlich.