# Two Dative elements in one sentence?

Tags: dative

In the sentence:

> Sie hat ihm aus dem Urlaub geschrieben

"aus dem Urlaub" is Dative, due to the usage of the preposition "aus", but "ihm" also seems to be Dative, and would make sense, as it answers the question "whom" (wem?)

Is it indeed the case or I got it wrong? Are two Dative elements in one sentence allowed?

Comment: Essentially the same question: [How can be there two accusative in one sentence?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39020/how-can-be-there-two-accusative-in-one-sentence)

Answer (score 5):

*Objects* of any case are typically not allowed more than once, like in (using a dative and an accusative object)

> Er gab dem Hund den Knochen

(And an example for mixing a genitive object with another object of any other case I would say is not possible as well until someone comes up with an example),

but prepositional constructs (where the preposition asks for a specific case) like in your example and adverbials of any case are allowed as much as you like (within reason, my example is close to a sensible limit or over):

> Er gab dem Hund auf dem Teppich in der Küche den Knochen des Beins des Ochsen aus dem Kühlschrank direkt in das Maul.

Answer (score 5):

There is **no such rule** that would limit the occassions of each case to a maximum of one.

> Sie hat ihm aus dem Urlaub geschrieben.

Here you have a dative object and an adverbial of origin that uses the preposition *aus* which takes dative case.

---

There's even verbs as *abfragen* that take two accusative objects, and you could add a modal *lassen* with its own accusative object, and an adverbial accusative as *den ganzen Tag lang* and have four accusatives in a row. Without a single preposition involved.

> Der Meister lässt den Gesellen den Lehrling den ganzen Tag lang den Prüfungsstoff abfragen.

Comment: Excellent example of a swarm of accusatives!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. WEM wurde geschrieben & WOHER wurde geschrieben. Both needs Dative - see [Lokale Präpositionen](https://deutschlernerblog.de/lokale-praepositionen-deutsch-ortsangaben-wo-wohin-woher/)

There is no "Lokative" in German: [Wikipedia: Lokativ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lokativ)

> Im Germanischen ist der Lokativ vor Beginn der schriftlichen
> Überlieferung mit dem Dativ zusammengefallen.

Comment: Du wärst wahrscheinlich erstaunt, wie wenig einem Nichtmuttersprachler die Methode "Frag danach und du kennst den Fall", die jedes Grundschulkind anwendet, wirklich hilft. Nämlich leider gar nicht. Wenn du's nicht "in den Ohren hast", weil du mit der Sprache groß geworden bist, dann weißt du auch nicht, wie du danach fragen sollst.

Answer (score -3):

Typologically, the rule which forbids this is *agreement*. However, German doesn't have strictly obligatory agreement, so dative singular masculine nouns for example carry no case ending. On the other end of the extreme, analytical languages get away without case ending and it still somehow works.

On a sentence level, the two datives are not on the same level of the syntax tree:

> Sie hat ihm [einen Brief (aus dem Urlaub)] geschrieben.

That's an accusative object with a dative argument.

Two datives don't seem to possible in such a configuration (I think).

It may be questionable how relevant this is. One could alternatively parse *aus dem Urlaub* as a separable prefix to the verb, like a prepositional adverb, quite analytical.

> She wrote to **him** **from** England

NB: cp. Old High German *fram*, Lat. *primus* “Zu-
grunde liegt eine Ableitung mit dem u. a. Super-
lative bildenden Suffix **-mó-* von der uridg.
Präp. **pro* ‚vor‘”; subtext: “Im Aind. werden mittels des betonten Suffixes **-mó-* Adjektive von Lokaladverbien in superlativischer Be-
deutung abgeleitet;" (EWA: [fram](https://ewa.saw-leipzig.de/articles/fram/de#fram)).

---

It is probably not either dative or locative in origin. If it looks like dative, stems of different gender/number follow suit, this may be *analogy*.

The opposition of prepositions is usually:

- *ins Haus, aus'em Haus,*
- *im Haus, außer Haus*

The reconstruction of Anatolian, a distantly related branch of Indo-European languages, serves for comparison:

> Hitt. and CLuw. *andan* are connected with Greek ἔνδον ‘in, at home’ and reconstructed as a Proto-Indo-European univerbation of **en dom* ‘at home’ (cf. HEG A-K:33, HED A:76f., EDHIL:185 “**h1ndom*”, LIPP II:159, Brosch 2014a:364-366).

(Dr. David Sasseville in: The Digital Philological-Etymological Dictionary of the Minor Anatolian Corpus Languages (eDiAna) https://www.ediana.gwi.uni-muenchen.de/dictionary.php?lemma=3443#31 (accessed 2023))

**dom-* is the reconstructed stem of *dome* (Latin *dom-us*), related to the root of *timber* and German *Zimmermann* (“carpenter”).

Corollary: We have to assume that *aus'm* is correct with /s/ reflecting the sound change *s, z, ß* < **t* < **d* (cp. *Füße*, Latin *pedes* "feet", ß "ess-zett" a ligature of *sz* in older spelling). The articles of *aus dem, in das, in dem* represent a kind of hypercorrection since the proto-language has no articles.

Caution: The regular reconstruction of the preposition is **ut* < **ud* and there is no extra evidence of ***udom* that I'm aware of.

The reconstructed Proto-Indo-European root **dem-* "to build" is not clearly related to the locative ending, cp. Lat. loc. *domī* ~ *domibus*, equivalently English *outa, out of* (note affricated *b* > English *v*, cf. Ger. *Liebe* "love"), Lithuanian *namè ~ *namuosè* and Sanskrit *dáme* ~ *dámayoḥ* ~ *dámeṣu* likely representing the original situation (Wiktionary: PIE [**dṓm*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/d%E1%B9%93m)). In particular, is not related to **de* "to", cp. *into* (and Ger. *ins*, I say).

This theory is woefully incomplete. The main takeaway is that the reconstruction follows from the modern grammar of multiple languages, which is biased by a select few earlier attested, inherited languages, which wildly disagree.

---

*Urlaub* is not a place anyway. Derived from *erlauben*, the etymology is opaque (cp. *allow*, not *leave* "vaccation"). As for *er-*, the rhotic may be due to rhotacism from **s* (cf. *ich war* "I was"). This is the case of *where*, from **hwaz* < **kʷos, *kʷis* (Wiktionary: PG [**hwar*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/hwar)). Hence the correlative question **"Woher?"** (cp. *hin und her* "to and fro", *hier und da*, "mit lokalem r-Suffix gebildet", DWDS/Pfeifet)

This implies, ironically, that *ur-* is in this case a reflection of *aus* "out" as in *Auslauf* (“Möglichkeit sich im freien zu bewegen, spielen, ..." DWDS, probably a narrowed sense of *exercise*, *run*, *run-out*, cf. Collins), cp. Old Frisian *ur* "out", and potentially related to Hittite *u-* "go", PIE **h2ew-* "out"; difficult to say. *-s* might be locative (Adams 2014: Tocharian B “nes”; Hackstein 2023 *s.v.* “s-mobile”, *r-Suffix*, Pfeifer above).