# "Wen nannte man den eisernen Kanzler" - Warum "wen"?

Tags: grammatical-case

I am having trouble understanding why is Wen used in this question instead of Wer.

> Wen nannte man den eisernen Kanzler?

Wen is used to ask for a direct object (accusative), but it looks to me in this example that the question is referred to the subject of the sentence, that is who is the person doing the action of calling himself the Iron Chancellor. Then why is it not

> Wer nannte man den eisernen Kanzler?

In this other sentence:

Wen hast du gesehen? Ich haben meinen Bruder gesehen, clearly Wen is asking about the object, since the subject is "Ich".

In the previous sentence, how would I formulate a long answer, to help me see why it is accusative?

My try:

> Man nannte Otto den eisernen Kanzler

Note: I suspect the impersonal "man" here may be confusing me.

Comment: Ginge es um eine Selbstbezeichnung hieße es "Wer nannte sich den Eisernen Kanzler".

Comment: It's related to your question: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11074/how-come-there-are-two-accusative-objects-here-das-geht-dich-einen-dreck-an/11106#11106

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding the sentence

> Wen nannte man den eisernen Kanzler?

OP states

> Wen is used to ask for a direct object (accusative), but it looks to me in this example that the question is referred to the subject of the sentence, that is who is the person doing the action of calling himself the Iron Chancellor.

Which is incorrect. The question is not about **who is calling** someone the Iron Chancellor (*man*), but about **who is being called** that (*Bismarck*).

> **Ich** nannte **ihn** einen Lügner.
>   **Wer** nannte ihn einen Lügner? – **Ich**.
>   **Wen** nannte ich einen Lügner? - **Ihn**.

As with any other verb, subject and object can refer to the same person.

> **Ich** nannte **mich** einen Lügner.

Despite the fact that *einen Lügner* is accusative, it is not an accusative object. It is questioned by *wie*, not *wen*; it can be pronominalised by *so*; its case is linked to that of the accusative object and not governed by the verb.

> **Wie** nannte man ihn? – **Den Eisernen Kanzler**.
>   Warum nannte man ihn **so**? (**so** = **den Eisernen Kanzler**)
>   **Er** wurde (von den Leuten) **der eiserne Kanzler** genannt.

Comment: If it is not an accusative object, why is it using the accusative case?, what is the grammar rule behind it?

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver This phenomenon is called "Gleichsetzungsakkusativ". Likewise the "Gleichsetzungsnominativ" exist, which, for example, appears in sentences like "Ich bin ein Maler." "Ich" and "ein Maler" are nominativ.

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver I'd say it's a pretty unique thing, basically limited to *nennen* and some similarly used verbs (*schimpfen*, *schelten*; *heißen* in old-fashioned use). One could liken it to a predicative, as idmean did.

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver: A more general term for _Gleichsetzungsakkusativ_ is _Objektprädikativ_. An _Objektprädikativ_ refers to the accusative object and can be an adjective (_ich finde den Film gut_) or an _als-phrase_ (_man kennt ihn als hilfsbereiten Kollegen_) or a prepositional object (_alle halten das für einen sehr schwierigen Job_) or structures like: Der Brief versetzte ihn _in Hochstimmung_. Ich halte das _für (zu) schwer_. Halte mir bitte mal die Tür _auf_. Bring das wieder _in Ordnung_. Die Anwaltskosten machten ihn _zum Bettler_. Jemand fand das Handy _unversehrt da liegen_...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is unrelated to the impersonal *man*, it is simply the phrase, because *jemanden etwas nennen* see [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/nennen) in the meaning *jmdn als etwas bezeichnen* requires two accusative objects, the person/thing to be labeled and the label itself.

> Ich nenne dich einen Betrüger.

Comment: Man nannte Otto den eisernen Kanszler?....is the answer "Man nannte Otto den eisernen Kanszler" correct? or should it be "Otto nannte man den eisernen Kansler",  but  I feel it should be sich instead of man for it to make sense

Comment: Yes in principle, but the noun correctly spells *Kanzler*, and  one would definitely use *Bismarck* instead of his first name. (Names of kings are an exception here.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd argue your misunderstanding is indeed centered around your confusion about "man": In

> Wen nannte man den eisernen Kanzler?

"man" is actually the subject. Your attempt to write a long answer instinctively came out right:

> Man nannte Otto den eisernen Kanzler.

Here, it becomes clearer how "man" actually has the role of the subject in the sentence.

Thus, it is actually the very same structure as in your other example

> Wen hast du gesehen?

Answer (score 1):

It's a [double accusative](https://en.easy-deutsch.de/list-double-accusative-verbs/).

*Man* has nothing to do with it. Rather, it can be used with certain verbs. Among them is

> jemanden etwas *nennen*.

It's actually similar in English, altough you don't notice cases. Consider this:

> Peter nannte den Akrobaten einen Schlangenmenschen.

=

> Peter called the acrobat a contortionist.

Maybe rephrasing it in the passive voice helps you:

> Der Akrobat wurde von Peter einen Schlangenmenschen genannt.

edit: David Vogt pointed out that *einen Schlangenmenschen* is wrong. It's *ein Schlagenmensch*, in the Gleichsetzungsnominativ case.

Comment: so would it be.."Otto von Bismark wurde von sie eisernen Kanzler genannt", where I am trying to put the impersonal man in the "sie"=they

Comment: Good for the most part. I think you've understood the function of *man*. But because it's impersonal and you can construct passive sentences without an agent, you can just disregard it in the active voice. It is usually not substituted by sie (what's more: it would be *von ihnen* (dative), not *von sie).

Comment: Our result would be: _*Otto von Bismarck wurde den eisernen Kanzler genannt._ BUT this is wrong. I would write: _Otto von Bismarck wurde der "Eiserne Kanzler" genannt_ or _Otto von Bismarck wurde "Eiserner Kanzler" genannt._ Firstly, I see Eiserner Kanzler as a proper noun (like Iron Curtain) and therefore capitalize it. Secondly, what's the second accusative in the active voice becomes assimilated to the first accusative – rendering both nominative; i.e. _der Eiserne Kanzler_, not _den Eisernen Kanzler_. Or, respectively, _Eiserner Kanzler_, not _Eisernen Kanzler_.

Comment: Still, my _Schlangenmensch_ sentence holds true, and I think it represents the regular construction. There are some irregularities, as with proper names or in cases outlined [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bb7b/a7f21b91ce8897f13469b851b9fc9b20a81e.pdf).

Comment: In https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-german/they+called+him+the     you can seen they use accusative in similar sentences. Besides, if they were nominative, again, the question should be formulated with Wer

Comment: Yes, this confirms the rule: accusative. But it does not preclude irregularities. On a side note: The question would, maybe surprisingly, be *__Wie__ nannte man Bismarck?* Like in English, *How did people call Bismarck?*

Comment: but the question was "Wen nannte man den eisernen Kanzler?"

Comment: Oh, I see now what you mean. "Wen" asks for the first accusative object – _Otto_ or _den Akrobaten_. "Wie" asks for the second accusative object – _den Eisernen Kanzler_ or _einen Schlangenmenschen_.

Comment: Der Akkusativ im letzten Beispiel ist falsch.

Comment: @DavidVogt Hast recht.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following simple Phrase:

```
"Peter liebt den Hund."
```

If you wanted to know, who loves the dog, you would simply ask:

- **WER** liebt den Hund? (**Peter** liebt den Hund. (**wer** -> nominative))

But if you wanted to know, **whom** Peter loves, you would ask:

Peter liebt **WEN**? (Peter liebt **den** Hund. (Here reflects the accusative in the question.))

If you wanted to figure out, in German, who loves whom, you would ask:

- **WER** liebt **WEN**?

If you ask for the subject of the sentence, you use : **WER**, if you ask for the accusative object, you use **WEN**, if you ask for the dative object, you use **WEM**, like when someone tells you, in German:

Ich habe **jemandem** geholfen, (I helped someone) and you wanted to discover, whom did I help, you would ask:

- **WEM** hast du geholfen? (Because "helfen" is a verb you use with dative.)

And from your initial question: "Man nannte Otto **den** eisernen Kanzler", you would ask for the accusative object of the sentence, keeping the declination:

- **WEN** nannte man (Otto,) den eisernen Kanzler?

der  -> WER (nominative)
dessen -> WESSEN (genitive)
dem   -> WEM (dative)
den  -> WEN (accusative)

Comment: does the following sentence makes sense: "Wer nannte sich den eisernen Kanzler? " , trying to say: "Who called himself xxx?", assuming the action of calling someone xxx was made by Otto himself and not by the people. In this case, it would be correct to use wer, I guess

Comment: The question would make sense, yes. The answer would be: Otto nannte sich den einsernen Kanzler ...

Comment: Ich denke, 'der eiserne Kanzler' ist eine feste Wendung, sodass Frage und Antwort lauten müssten: "Wer nannte sich der eiserne Kanzler?"   "Otto nannte sich der eiserne Kanzler"

Comment: @Holger  Ich denke, beide Formulierungen sind akzeptabel. Mit Kasuskongruenz klingt es etwas solider, schwergewichtiger, ohne Kasuskongruenz klingt es mehr wie Alltagsdeutsch. Apropos solide: Wer nannte sich ein stabiles Genie?