# let somebody do something (for you)?

Tags: grammar-identification

Here is the context, I have bought something and have the seller bring the stuff to my house because it is too heavy. They can do it for free, or I need to additionally pay for the transport cost. If translating this to german, it sounds weird (not sure if it's correct):

- Ich *lasse* **sie** **das Möbel** ins Haus *bringen*.

"Sie" and "das Möbel" are of accusative objects.

On the internet, I found in this similar context, only **one object** is used, for example:

- Man *lässt* **den Fernseher** *laufen*, wenn Besuch kommt. (active)
- Ich *lasse* morgen **meine Haare** *schneiden*. (passive)

In english, we simply say: "I have the seller bring the furniture to my house". How can I express the same idea in german? (with two objects at the same time: the seller and the furniture).

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach, please do not use moderator privileges to close a question unless it is a very obvious case.

Comment: The question has some aspects (especially the whether two accusative objects are acceptable) which are not covered by a dictionary.

Comment: @CarstenS I think, this is an obvious case. leo.org, which I linked in my explanatory comment, says "jmdn. etw. [acc.] tun lassen", so I would say, it does answer the question, whether two accusative objects are acceptable. You seem to have a different point of view. What is it that I am overseeing?

Comment: Following the suggested link, I got the answer ("Ich lasse meine Tochter ihr Zimmer aufräumen."). Although the entry in the dictionary is about "have somebody do something", it is close to what I want ("let somebody do something").

Comment: I think "Ich lasse morgen meine Haare schneiden." is not passive. Passive is "Die Haare werden geschnitten", i.e. "The hair is cut", "lassen" (let) does not make the sentence passive. It has a fixed form (werden + perfekt or sein + perfekt).

Comment: Related [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/55932/1696), since there are other scenarios requiring two accusatives.

Comment: Part of the strange sound is caused by not using the standard phrase *liefern lassen* as in *Ich lasse den Händler das/die Möbel liefern*.

Comment: Related is https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11074/how-come-there-are-two-accusative-objects-here-das-geht-dich-einen-dreck-an

Answer (score 1):

A [dictionary lookup](https://dict.leo.org/german-english/to%20have%20so.%20do%20sth.) tells us that *to have someone do something* translates to *jmndn. etw.<sup>acc.</sup> tun lassen*.

[*jmndn.*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jmdn.) is short for *jemanden*, which in turn is the acccusative form of *jemand*, and [*etw.*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/etw.) is short for *etwas*. Since the dictionary explicitely states that *etw.* must be accusative as well, we can take from there that it is totally fine to have two accusative objects in this construction: The person who is made to do something, as well as the thing that is being done. So, yes,

> Ich lasse sie das Möbel ins Haus bringen.

is correct. If you were referring to plural furniture, it would be

> Ich lasse sie die Möbel ins Haus bringen.

Comment: The word Möbel is mostly used in the plural, so "das Möbel ins Haus bringen" (even if it is correct) can sound unnatural. It would be better to say "das Möbelstück ins Haus bringen".